# What is the significance of "WorkerSupportCancellation" in Backgroundworker C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, background

I guess the default behaviour is, the user can cancel the long running process when I implement it with background worker. What is the significance of WorkerSupportCancellation" ?

1. If I don't use this WorkerSupportCancellation as true, the user will not be able to cancel ? Or to put it in other way,  is it mandatory to define this ?
2. If the answer to question one is "not mandatory", then why is this a feature that MS has come up with ? I don't see any good reason to stop the user from cancelling the process, its duly on his choice. What scenario this feature can fit ?

Could someone please throw some light on this.

Comment: This is a kind of check. You started a background worker and now at some time you want to stop it. What you do here is set cancellation property true. And when you want to cancel your worker just call CancelAsync. This will generate a message or flag which can be used in background worker to stop executing.

Comment: Okay its in designer. Jeez, it confuses a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WorkerSupportCancellation` must be set to true in order to support asynchronous cancellation. Otherwise calling `CancelAsync()` throws an `InvalidOperationException`. So, in response to your questions:

1. Yes this must be true for the user to cancel. It is only mandatory if having the ability to cancel is mandatory.
2. Depending on the requirements for your application, you may want to perform a task on the background such as database queries, interacting with the file system, etc... that must be completed and perhaps are not initiated by the user. So there are certainly cases where asynchronous cancellation may not be required, for most user initiated actions cancellation is a good feature to support.

Here's some additional information on [WorkerSupportsCancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workersupportscancellation.aspx) & [BackgroundWorkers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it must be set to `true` to allow an asynchronous cancellation.  Calling `CancelAsync()` on a BackgroundWorker that has `WorkerSupportsCancellation` set to `false` will result in an `InvalidOperationException`.

see : [BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync.aspx)

Comment: When I don't declare it at all either as true/false, I will still be able to cancel right ?

Comment: @Divine - The default value for `WorkerSupportsCancellation` is `false`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workersupportscancellation.aspx

Comment: in the backgroundWorker_DoWork method, check in a loop the value of backgroundWorker.CancellationPending. If true, a Cancel has been invoke (by backgroundWorker.CancelAsync())

Answer (score 4):

I believe it throws an `InvalidOperationException` if you try to cancel it without this being set, so it is imdeed mandatory.

The only reason I can see for designing it this way, is for the person who writes the worker to indicate if it's possible to cancel or not. Not all `BackgroundWorkers` will logically be possible to cancel, so it makes it easier for the person using the worker to see if it's possible to cancel or not.